# Memory stress testing tool?

Tags: android, stress-testing

Are there any memory stress testing tools for Android?  Need to work on real devices.

I am working on an app using Ant+ based sensors. http://www.thisisant.com/.  I want to split things up so I have a service dealing with the Ant radio and broadcasting higher level intents that can be picked up by multiple apps.  I want to keep this service seprate from the rest of my application as this functionality should realy be being provided by the standard Ant Apis.

My main aplication has a data logging service and activities to desplay the data.  The data logging needs to continue while the user may be doing somthing else and thus causing memory issues.

So I have multiple services and Apps and want to experiment with what the best setup is e.g. remote / local rervices, sharing processes etc. I want to be able to test things under low memory senarios in a controlled sort of a manner.  Hence the need for a memory stress tool.

I have done some googeling and have not turned anything up which is suprising as Android phones are memory scares devices and have some quirky behaivure so good testing tools seem like somthing that should exist.

Further Information.

I found this today http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=622666 A discussion on how the taskkiller can be configured on a rooted phone.  Modifying the configurationv values to artificialy cut down the memory the system has may be a way of getting into the low memory senario more easaly.  I have written a simple app that allocates memory in a configurable way, but there is a limit as to how much you can easaly allocate in a single process.

Comment: Unintentionally, I asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25179330/1009459

Comment: The fact there is nothing in the toolset for doing this is disappointing it should be a standard system tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=derekwilson.net.rameater

I am bias (I wrote it) but it works fine and is being used by a number of devs. No special permissions are required.