# CPU, RAM stress android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, cpu, ram

I have a task to compare the performance of Java and Kotlin programs. I would like to measure CPU memory and RAM usage. I read somewhere that a good idea for CPU stress is to generate random numbers and sort them, however I have a problem how to stress RAM. What is the ways can to stress CPU and RAM in android?

Comment: You can do this from the profiler tab at the bottom of android studio. But first make sure you start the emulator correctly

Comment: I think you don't understand me or i make a mistake in my question. I know how to check na usage of RAM or CPU but i have a problem how to increase of usage it. By generate random numbers and sort them i increase usage CPU. How increase usage RAM?

Comment: In the articles I read, I saw that this is not possible, it can only be forced up to 500 mb.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179330/stresstest-memory-on-android

Comment: Given that Java and Kotlin translate to similar byte code that gets run by the same JVM, I doubt this is a useful benchmark.